# How to send SNS Notification from one user to another with using their Usernames?

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cognito

In my Mobile APP, Cognito user pool is installed and i want to send a notification from one User to another User (such as sending him an invitation and asking his confirmation).

I have Lambda function and when User 1 (from APP) trigger Lambda function (written in Python 2.7) to send an invitation to User 2, in first, Lambda function is looking for that User 2 is available in the pool or not. Till this moment no problem, but after he found that User 2 is available in the pool, Lambda function has to send a notification (with JSON data) to User 2 but Lambda function only know the Username of the User 2, he does not know about TargetArn ([EndpointArn](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish)).  I do not want to use DynamoDB for mapping as seen in the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439656/aws-sns-publish-to-specific-user-via-cognito-identity-id).

How can i send notification from one user to another with only using their Usernames?

Comment: YOUR CAPS LOCK IS ON! + **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask.

Comment: Writing in ALL CAPS is considered SCREAMING and rud.